# Specify different path for assets and resources folders - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I need to build my project with the option to use different assets and resources folders. So instead of manually replacing the assets and resources folders, I want to know if there is any way in gradle.build or any library to specify the path of those folders.

I came across [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) article which refer something about different flavors. Is this the right approach? If yes, how can I change the paths of the folders?

```
productFlavors {
    flavor2 {
    }
    flavor1 {
    }
}

sourceSets{

    flavor2 {
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        assets.srcDirs = ['/mybuilds/f2assets']
        res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor2','res']
    }

    flavor1 {
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        assets.srcDirs = ['/mybuilds/f1assets']
        res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor1','res']
    }

}
```

I am not sure how to use the different paths. Why "resources.srcDirs" has 2 paths?

Comment: Build flavours are meant to create different variety of same type of application. For example if you need to create an application for school students studying in 10th Grade/ 9th Grade etc. Now you will not be able to create different application for each. Instead using build flavours you will be able to create different applications in parallel using majority of same code and specific code to each application. http://www.androidauthority.com/building-multiple-flavors-android-app-706436/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build flavors is the right approach. The names of the folders are done automatically, so no need for the code you added in the gradle. The only thing you need to do is under app/src - add a folder with the name of the flavor, and there you can add the res folder that is different. When you make a build just choose the right flavor from the Build Variants view on the left bottom of Android Studio. Your project structure should look like this:

```
project/app/src/main
project/app/src/flavor1/res
project/app/src/flavor2/res
```

and in the gradle:

```
productFlavors {
  flavor2 {
  }
  flavor1 {
  }
}
```

Notice that gradle will take the resources from the main folder by default, and if it does not exist it will search in the flavor. So make sure you have the different resources in the flavor folders, and not in the main folder.

Comment: You can also put a `java` directory in the flavor directories if needed.  You just need to make sure that every flavor has all the classes it needs (which is to say classes that aren't contained in the main source set but are referenced from there), and that classes are not duplicated (for example defined in both main and a flavor).

Comment: I tried it, but it loads the main res files too on the project structure. The new res files are with red color, so they won't be used on runtime. Check the image below:
http://imgur.com/a/Nx11z